# MySQL Select MIN DateTime when DateTime is set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL Query that is ran that gets me a start date for a Gantt chart of Project Tasks I am building.

It works great as long as all my Project Tasks have a Start Date set, however Tasks that are not "started" yet have a `start_date` value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`  This result in my Gantt chart trying to build a chart with like 16,343 days

```
SELECT MIN( date_started ) AS start_date
FROM apoll_web_projects_tasks
WHERE project_id =  '205e34c6-7381-92eb-e6ab-54125429cd2a'
```

Is there a way to get the value I want but disregarding any values of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `WHERE date_started != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` like this:

```
SELECT MIN( date_started ) AS start_date
FROM apoll_web_projects_tasks
WHERE project_id =  '205e34c6-7381-92eb-e6ab-54125429cd2a'
AND date_started != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```